# Objective-C Sockets with WebServer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, websocket

I'm working on an App for iOS that needs to send data from one user to another. Currently I'm saving the data in a MySQL Database using an HTTP connection to a PHP file. This will then be downloaded from the receiving user, who uses pulling (I think thats what its called) to check for new data.
But this is slow and not very efficient. 
I've been looking into Sockets but I don't really know where to start. I have a web server which should handle the communication but I don't know if I always will need the database, since sometimes the users are online at the same time and may are able to send the information between each other without saving it in the database?
Maybe someone knows where to start and what to consider. Would be a great help!

Thank you so much :)
Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [CoreWebSocket!](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket). It's pretty good so far. Best of all, i found it very easy to understand. It might be a good place to start.

I also know of [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket). Which I'm told is actually better. But I've been working with CoreWebSocket for a while now, and its working just fine to me.

Both are pretty well documented. So I think these would be a good place to start. Let me know if you need anything else.

Thats just the sockets though. I also have an 'always online' based application. Where the users are always online. The good thing is, sockets are persistent in the sense that you make the connection only once. For this you need some kind of turn server to figure out who's online and their credentials to connect. Once connected you can seamlessly send receive data between them with out involving an in-between server.

If you need to be aware of what the users are sending and receiving, then its a good idea to have a server in-between, Where data is sent to the server first, and then forwarded to the appropriate users.

The libraries above have some documentation on how they work, so you can use it to figure out some kind of architecture before you pick one of them to use.

Good luck!

EDIT: To be honest, sockets are meant for (in my opinion) live connections. So if you want to send and receive controls for a game or something of that sorts. The idea is that you don't need establish a new connection every time you want to send data. You make a connection once, and you can send and receive until it is closed. Is this the kind of application you're trying to make?

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll see how far I get! I just don't really understand how it'll work if one user for example doesn't have internet when another sends him data. At least then it has to be saved in a database right? And do the sockets even help in this case?

Comment: Of course if a user does not have internet then no. However, here's what you can do. IF they dont have internet, a socket connection will not be established. You can then make a note on the ios device that nothing has been sent. So on your next try you can send all the data from the previous event as well. The reason you will need a server is because these users will need a way to find each other. So there has to be some kind of mediator. A turn server. There a some really basic NodeJS servers you can look into.

Comment: Thank you :) And yes thats what I want. It's like a chat application where they communicate basically. I'll look into that thank you :)))

Comment: You said they are well documented? Is it just the documentation on their github page or is there more to it? because I can't find the right place to start coding.

Comment: Which one are you using? SocketRocket? or CoreWebSocket?

Comment: Im using SocketRocket